# how can I insert commas to multiple columns in a textfile with regular expression and notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

is it possible to use a regex find/replace to add multiple commas into a text file using notepad++? My workplace doesn't allow any type of addons or programming tools.

example:
I would like to add commas at column 3 and column 5
12345678
result
12,3,45678

find: ^(.{3})
replace \1,

i see the above solution works for one comma, is there a way to add a series of commas to a line?

Comment: Replace `^(.{2})(.)` with `\1,\2,`? Alternatively, you could use `Edit > Column Editor` to insert the comma and repeat for each position.

Comment: Find what: `^(\d{3})(\d{2})`    Replace with: `$1,$2,` or  `\1,\2,`   and result `123,45,678`